# Problems with an IF statement in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

When I type in an ID number for the game, I always gets the 3rd statement of my if else expression. Where am I going wrong?!!

```
<html>
<body>
<p>Type in the ID and hit search:</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Search</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
    <form>
        <input id="textbox" type="text" />
    </form>
<script>
var textboxValue = document.getElementById("textbox").value;
function myFunction() {
    var message;
    if (textboxValue == 1) {
        message = "Fantasy World";
    } else if (textboxValue == 2) {
        message = "Sir Wags A Lot";
    } else {
        message = "Take a Path";
    }
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = message;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is you always test the same, initial, value of the input.

Change

```
var textboxValue = document.getElementById("textbox").value;
function myFunction() {
```

to

```
function myFunction() {
    var textboxValue = document.getElementById("textbox").value;
```

This way the value will be read each time the function is called.

Comment: Can the downvoter explain the problem in my answer ?

Comment: @dystroy Thank you dystroy. That's really helpful.  People like you help newbies like me to improve and I am extremely grateful

Answer (score 4):

Put this statement:

```
var textboxValue = document.getElementById("textbox").value;
```

Inside the function.

Comment: I edited your answer to change the code formatting from a quote (you get this with ctrl-Q) to a code bloc (you get that with Ctrl-K).